# query_posts exclude a meta key

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 1000, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', 'meta_key' => featured_product, 'meta_value' => 1)); ?>


<?php query_posts(array('showposts' => 1000, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'ASC')); ?>
```

I have 2 queries, first to show meta key with featured_product eq 1. So I want to exclude all the featured products on the second query. How can i do that please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need the [meta_compare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) for that:

```
<?php query_posts(
  array(
   'showposts' => 1000, 
   'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
   'post_type' => 'page', 
   'orderby' => 'title', 
   'order' => 'ASC', 
   'meta_key' => 'featured_product', 
   'meta_compare' => '!=', 
   'meta_value' => 1
  )
); ?>
```

Comment: you mean 'meta_compare' => '!=' right? I tried that won't work to me. showing nothing on the 2rd query. thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Are you sure that the rest of your query is correct. Maybe try to use only the meta_* values and check all the fields that are returned.

Answer (score 2):

While looping through your first query, build an array consisting of the ids of the posts in the loop. Then use pass this array to the second query using "post__not_in" => $your_array